# Product edit so slow on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, edit

I have a Magento 2 store with around 20k products, and when I try to edit a product, it loading up the content and showing a spinner, but after few seconds, page freezes. But I see the content loaded behind the transparent loader background. But still the page is not accessible and browser asks to kill the page or wait.

Please see the image below,
[image]

Comment: Are you seeing this error in chrome. if so chk this link https://mage2.pro/t/topic/278, https://customercenter.karthost.com/knowledgebase/125/Using-Google-Chrome---The-pages-have-become-unresponsive-Wait-or-Kill-message.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
But I see no any error in my browser console, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: If possible chk with some other browser as well,  try after clearing cache both of browser & magento

Comment: I did check on Chrome, FF and Edge, same results on each browser and cleaned the caches too.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your Magento cache from

```
system -> Cache Management
```

If that didn't fix the issue check error logs.

Comment: I have turned on the caches in cache management, but situation still the same.

Comment: check your error logs including apache server log if you need